# Template specializations

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading the book C++ Templates: The Complete Guide by Addison Wesley, and have a question about specializations of class templates. I understand how it works, but I have trouble understanding when you would use this feature from the given example. Here is the general definition of a Stack class:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <stdexcept> 

template <typename T> 
class Stack { 
  private: 
    std::vector<T> elems;     // elements 

  public: 
    void push(T const&);      // push element 
    void pop();               // pop element 
    T top() const;            // return top element 
    bool empty() const {      // return whether the stack is empty 
        return elems.empty(); 
    } 
};
```

And here is the specialization

```
#include <deque> 
#include <string> 
#include <stdexcept> 
#include "stack1.hpp" 

template<> 
class Stack<std::string> { 
  private: 
    std::deque<std::string> elems;  // elements 

  public: 
    void push(std::string const&);  // push element 
    void pop();                     // pop element 
    std::string top() const;        // return top element 
    bool empty() const {            // return whether the stack is empty 
        return elems.empty(); 
    } 
};
```

My problem with this is that it seems to break OOP principles about encapsulation. Would a client need to know that there are two definitions, maybe in to different header files, and then know which one to include based on the type T given to the Stack class? It seems to me that you would be better of just implementing two different classes for in this scenario, one general Stack class and a specialized StackString class.

Thoughts?

Comment: Usually you'd include the specialization in the same header. The user would not need to know they are using a specialization.

Comment: @juanchopanza _"The user would not need to know they are using a specialization."_ I was just about to say the same, + unless the behavior of the interface is changed by the specialization (which is considered wrong of course).

Comment: If you are not able to modify the file in which `Stack` is defined, create another file, say `MyStack.h` and add the specialization in that file. Make  sure to `#include` `MyStack.h` instead of `Stack.h`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. You still have the possible problem of someone including stack_specialization.h instead of stack.h though, but that's a minor issue I guess. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @RSahu I find that including seceral class definitions in one file clutters the file, so I think I would go for the second approach even if I could modify Stack.h. Thanks

Comment: Using a separate file for the specialization makes it possible to instantiate a `Stack<std::string>` that does not use the specialization (by including the 'wrong' file). Placing the specialization in the same file makes this type of error impossible, so it's clearly a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would a client need to know that there are two definitions, maybe in
>   to different header files, and then know which one to include based on
>   the type T given to the Stack class?

There is absolutely no need to put them into two different *open* headers, i.e. headers that the user of a library will see and use. They might be internally organized in two different implementation headers, which then are included in the main one that the user will see and include. But the user will neither know that there *is* an explicit specialization, nor that he is *using* one.

```
// Stack.impl.hpp

// primary template:
template <typename T>
class Stack {
   // [...]
};

// Stack_StringSpec.impl.hpp

#include "Stack.impl.hpp"
// explicit specialization:
template <>
class Stack<std::string> {
   // [...]
};

// Stack.hpp

#include "Stack.impl.hpp" // Included for clarity
#include "Stack_StringSpec.impl.hpp"
```

Note that in most cases, a specialization will still be documented as it most certainly exists for a reason the user should/needs to be aware of. (Take `std::vector<bool>` as an example.)

Comment: How would this be done in practice? What is an open header file? This feels like the answer I was looking for, but I'm not completely following.

Answer (score 0):

A specialized class shares only the base name with the unspecialized variant, indeed you have to *totally* rewrite both the interface and the implementation, no previous code can be reused.

The most popular specialization is `std::vector<bool>`. The `bool` type takes 1 byte, but actually one byte could store 8 bools. When you need an array of bools it may seem reasonable to pack more of them in a single byte in order to reduce the memory consumption. The specialization here allows to achieve exactly this.

To the user everything is transparent: you use `vector<bool>` exactly as `vector<int>`, but while the second relies on a dynamic array of ints, the first plays with bits in a completely different manner.

The specialization doesn't necessary have to be in the same header, but it should be your care to make all the specializations visible when the user includes the class, otherwise he may fail to use them (you don't want to remember to include another file when you use a `vector<bool>`).